# PrimeNG Dropdown LazyLoad event not firing

Tags: primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have upgraded my Angular PrimeNG app from v9 to 11. Dropdown lazy loading has stopped working and event ***onBranchLazyLoadEvent*** isn't called now.  Below is the sample code

```
<p-dropdown id="field_branch" name="branch" [options]="branchOptions" formControlName="branchId"
    [virtualScroll]="true" [lazy]="true" [rows]="10" (onLazyLoad)="onBranchLazyLoadEvent($event)" [lazyLoadOnInit]="true" [filter]="true"
    placeholder="Choose" optionLabel="name" optionValue="id"></p-dropdown>
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the primeng 14 documentation says it's supported, it doesn't truly work. Not even on the example page and there is very little saying about this.

Answer (score 1):

Latest versions doesn't support dropdown lazyloading

Reference to latest dropdown source [dropdown source](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/v12.1.0/src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts)

Some open issues about it with working lazy dropdown repo fork by @yelhouti [7284](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7284)
[5955](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5955)

Comment: Still an issue in 2022, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Since primeng 14 this is again supported (below is their official example with lazy loading and virtual scroll).

```html
<h5>Virtual Scroll (100000 Items) and Lazy</h5>
<p-dropdown [options]="lazyItems" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem2" placeholder="Select Item" [virtualScroll]="true" [virtualScrollItemSize]="38" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="onLazyLoad($event)" [virtualScrollOptions]="{ showLoader: true, loading: loading, delay: 250 }">
    <ng-template pTemplate="loader" let-options="options">
        <div class="flex align-items-center py-2 px-3" style="height: 38px">
            <p-skeleton [width]="options.even ? '60%' : '50%'" height="1rem"></p-skeleton>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PrimeNG 13, where the option `lazy` doesn't exist, I managed to hack it like this (and I assume it will work for earlier versions like your 11):

```
<p-dropdown
    [options]="tags$ | async"
    formControlName="tag"
    appendTo="body"
    optionLabel="name"
    optionValue="code"
    [showClear]="true"
    [emptyMessage]="(areTagsLoaded$ | async) === true ? 'No tags found' : 'Loading tags...'"
    (onShow)="loadTags()">
    <ng-template let-tag pTemplate="item">
        <div>{{ tag.name }}</div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

The code above should be self-explanatory, you need to load your options in the `loadTags()` or `loadWhatever()` method and make sure you don't load them again, depending on your needs, by using an extra boolean like `areTagsLoaded`.

Comment: what about scrolling ? , your fix is not complete

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada this fixes the lazy loading part, in the sense that the options are loaded dynamically. It doesn't fix the virtual scrolling issue, which is far more complicated. If you need this, you can look for answers elsewhere 